# Conan add local project as dependency

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm starting to explore Conan package management. So far including dependencies present on the conan center has been trivial, but now I'm struggling including other local dependencies.

Suppose I have the following project structure:

```
|----Project_A
|        |
|        |-src
|        |  |...
|        |
|        |-CMakeLists.txt
|        |-conanfile.txt
|
|----Project_B
|        |
|        |-src
|        |  |...
|        |
|        |-CMakeLists.txt
```

I want Project_A to have Project_B as dependency. Project_B is already generating static libraries when built.

Is there a way using Conan to add that project as dependency? Meaning that it will build Project_B using the provided CMakeLists file and add it as dependency for Project_A?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a recipe for `Project_B` and install it in your local cache

Comment: If you have a single project, or maybe two, @AlanBirtles is right, just build as a local package and consume it from your cache. But if you need to work on several project at same time, you should try Workspaces feature: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/workspaces.html

Comment: The ``workspace`` feature is deprecated, the recommended approach is to use ``editables`` directly: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/editable_packages.html. Workspaces will be continued after 2.0.

Comment: @drodri is right, workspace is not a good option.